# Slide menu with storyboards ios 7

Tags: xcode, storyboard, slide

I need to implement on my app a Slide menu (like the one on the facebook app) but i also wants to have buttons on my Views that links to other Views, for example on my Main View I have a button that on click goes to OptionView but i also want to have a slide menu That links to OptionView, i'm using storyboards and xcode 5 and I wanted to know if someone can help me to figure out how to create the Slide menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use this to have an idea / use the open source:
     https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

or you can implement it like this:

Add to your navigation bar a `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightRevealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightRevealButtonItem;
```

**implement the `rightRevealToggle`:**

```
 - (void)rightRevealToggle:(id)sender
 {
     float width = self.view.frame.size.width;
     float height = self.view.frame.size.height;
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = FALSE;

     CGRect rearViewFrame = _rearViewController.view.frame;
     float deltaToMoveRearView = _rearViewController.datePicker.frame.size.width;//0.25f * width;
     //slide the rear view inside
     if(_rearViewController.view.hidden && ![sender isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]])
     {
         _rearViewController.view.hidden = FALSE;
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f animations:^{
             _rearViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(width - deltaToMoveRearView,rearViewFrame.origin.y,rearViewFrame.size.width,rearViewFrame.size.height);
        _contentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-deltaToMoveRearView , 0, width, _contentViewController.view.frame.size.height);
        NSLog(@"3: frame: x:%f y:%f",_contentViewController.view.frame.origin.x,_contentViewController.view.frame.origin.y);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = TRUE;
    }];
}
//slide the rear view outside
else
{
    self.rearViewController.view.hidden = FALSE;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f animations:^{
        _rearViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(width,rearViewFrame.origin.y,rearViewFrame.size.width,rearViewFrame.size.height);
        _contentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, _contentViewController.view.frame.size.height);
        self.titleLabel.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        _rearViewController.view.hidden = finished;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = TRUE;
    }];
    [self updateContentViewController];
}
}

 - (void)updateContentViewController
 {
     UIViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@VC",_rearViewController.selectedSection]];
     if([newVC class] == [ScoresViewController class])
     {
         if([_contentViewController  class] == [ScoresViewController class] &&
       [((ScoresViewController *) _contentViewController) date] != _rearViewController.datePicker.date)
         {
             ((ScoresViewController *) newVC).date = _rearViewController.datePicker.date;
             [self cycleToViewController:newVC];
         }
     }
     if([newVC class] != [_contentViewController class])
     {
         [self cycleToViewController:newVC];
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is _rearViewController Hear?

Answer (score 1):

see the below link with so many examples

[Code4App Menu](http://code4app.net/category/menu)